# How to work around a getter that also sets a member?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, constants, getter

I'm dealing with something that goes along these lines:

I have a class that is quite complex and a member that depends on some stuff that isn't set when the class is initialized, or is set on the go. Objects of that class make sense even when that member isn't set. It can also be reset depending on other changes that are made to other members.

Now, assume this "special" member is computationally-expensive to set, and so I'm delaying computing it on request.

So:

```
class Class
{
    X x;
    Y y;
    SpecialClass specialObject;
public:
    void setX(const X& newX);
    void setY(const Y& newY);

    //----
    SpecialClass getSpecialObject() /*const*/
    { 
        computeSpecialObject();
        return specialObject();
    }
private:
    void computeSpecialObject()
    {
        //specialObject depends on x and y
        //and is expensive to compute
        //this method is a bottleneck
    }
};
```

I don't want to call the `compute` method every time I change `x` or `y` because it's expensive, so I'm left with the dilemma:

- remove the `const`? Logically, the getter should be `const`, but it can't. There's also the downside that it can't be called on `const` objects.
- I can make `specialObject` `mutable`, but it doesn't seem like the right thing to do.
- cast away constness? Again, looks fishy.
- call `computeSpecialObject` before the get? - what if someone forgets? They'll get an out-dated result.

Is there a design pattern that deals with this? A good approach? Or is the class design just wrong? (I'd lean towards this last one, but changing the class isn't really an option)

Note: I've made the member `mutable`, want to know if there's a better solution.

Comment: If you always recalculate the special object when get is called, when do you actually use the cached value?  Could you just return a newly co structed object and remove the member variable all together?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can make specialObject `mutable`, but it doesn't seem like the right thing to do.

Why so? That's exactly why `mutable` exists: to allow a `const` function to be *logically* `const` without the need to physically leave the object unchanged (and if you make the object `mutable`, remember about [ensuring thread-safety](http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/C-and-Beyond-2012-Herb-Sutter-You-dont-know-blank-and-blank) - I'm sure you know what I mean).

This is true as long as the initialization of the `SpecialClass` object is not something that alters the logical state of the object, of course, because that's what `const` promises not to do.

In that case, the function itself is simply not `const` in nature, and it should likely be named something different than just `getSpecialObject()`: `computeAndReturnSpecialObject()` could be a candidate.

Comment: Yes, I know, seems reasonable, I just feel dirty adding `mutable` :(

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Maybe if it feels dirty it's because somehow it does alter the logical state of the object. Are there any functions whose logical behavior changes if `specialObject` is initialized? Like, they return something different when invoked while `specialObject` is initialized rather than uninitialized?

Comment: @Luchian `mutable` can feel a bit like a hack, but if you look at it from a slightly higher-level view, it should be clear that it's the right thing. The function doesn't alter the object per se, even if it does make changes. It merely restores/sets some invariants.

Comment: Yes, other stuff depends on it too, but they use the getter rather than the object.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: `mutable` was designed for this particular purpose. It allows you to maintain `const` on the signature of the methods and will ensure that only the mutable state can be modified. Also, consider adding a dirty flag to identify whether the `x` and `y` values have changed (also `mutable`) and only recompute the value if the flag is dirty.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: If other member functions depend on that field, and it might/might not be computed, and that makes your code depend on calling the function rather than accessing the member, then... you should consider refactoring that to a different object so that you (or other maintainers) don't by mistake access the uninitialized value (or worse off, initialized with the wrong `x` or `y` values)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Basically the important bit is that for every function `foo()` of `c`, the following assertion never fires: `Class c; auto x = c.foo(); c.getSpecialObject(); auto y = c.foo(); assert(x == y);`. It's actually more complex than that, but just to give an idea. From outside the object, one should not be able to infer any state change because of a call to `getSpecialObject()`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd leave the `const` and *either* make `specialObject` `mutable` or keep a *pointer* to the `specialObject` instead of just 'embedding' it into the class.

I would also add a `bool dirty` flag that is `mutable` and set it whenever a change is made that invalidates the computation. I would then check the flag inside `computeSpecialObject` and do the work only if it's set. Using a pointer, you could even `delete` the old computation object whenever a change invalidates an existing computation, but that opens a whole 'nother can of worms.

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

It's always a fine line this one, not calling it when you don't need to, versus introduces holes in caller, that mean it might not have been and returning incorrect results.

Me I'd move compute to be method of special object and the  treat this class as a wrapper for the arguments for the compute method that class. A bonus ball is you can unit test the computation.

Then it's just a question of deciding when you need to call SpecialObject.Compute(x,y) again or simply return the last result.
Another thing I might look at if I could, would be if X has changed but Y hasn't can I simplify the calculation. i.e. keep some intermediate results.

Not sure how applicable it is for you, but one of the things I regularly end up doing is injecting a something that does the compute, so I tend to fall into this pattern by default.

Answer (score 0):

There are two directions you could go, more `OOP` or more `Functional`. One involves caring less about state manipulation, but rather behaviour, the other completely forgets about behaviour, and cares about returned state.

### OOP

For me a key `OOP` principle is `Tell, Don't Ask`, or `write no getters or setters`.

Design your objects to be told what to do, to be autonomous. Don't ask it to return some object which you can then use to do something. Just tell it to do the thing you want in the first place. If you're telling an object to do something then you likely expect it to change state, and it's not right for it to be `const`.

Your `SpecialClass` may provide some service `doService()`. You can instead tell `Class` to `doSpecialService()`, which is rightly mutable.

An alternative is for the creation of this object to use some other object to do the creation. So a function can be const but take a non const parameter:

```
class Class {
public:
    void doService(ServiceProvider& serviceProvider) const {
        serviceProvider.doService(x, y);
    }
};
```

With this you would pass in a `SpecialServiceProvider&` which would create the correct `SpecialClass` for the given `X` and `Y`. It would be mutable. It would seem correct to modify state in the provision of the service. Maybe you could have a map caching `SpecialClass` objects for (`X`, `Y`) pairs.

### Functional

The other direction is to make your objects immutable. Whenever you want some new state create it using the old state as a basis. This could have a knock on effect until you have turtles (almost) all the way down:

```
class SpecialBuilder {
public:
    SpecialBuilder withX(const X& newX) const;
    SpecialBuilder withY(const Y& newY) const;
    SpecialClass build() const;
};

SpecialBuilder specialBuilder;
SpecialClass special = specialBuilder.withX(x).withY(y).build();
```

You can share data between each returned `SpecialBuilder` as it is immutable.